# Why am i getting undefined while trying to access the value in json data returned via ajax

Tags: javascript

data[0] correctly returns the 0th line of the json data but trying to access the key like service and online returns undefined.

```
 <script>
      $.ajax({
    url:"count.php",
    dataType:'json', 
    success: function(data, status){
      console.log(data[0].online);
    }
  });
    </script>
```

count.php

```
<?php 

$data = array();

 $data[] = file_get_contents('https://xxxxxik.php?%20metod=get_count_new%20&service=pro1&apikey=sdss');
  $data[] = file_get_contents('https://xxxxxik.com/priemnik.php?%20metod=get_count_new%20&service=pro2&apikey=sdds');
  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

console.log(data) prints the below json

```
[
  "{\"service\":\"pro1\",\"online\":91}",
  "{\"service\":\"pro2\",\"online\":0}"
]
```

Comment: The elements are string not object.

Comment: Looks like the file contents is JSON already, so when you `json_encode()` the array, the contents are re-encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `data` contains strings. You can use [`Array​.prototype​.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)and `JSON.parse()` to convert it to array of objects.

```
$.ajax({
   url:"count.php",
   dataType:'json', 
   success: function(data, status){
      data = data.map(x => JSON.parse(x))
      console.log(data[0].online)
   }
});
```

Comment: @cejirika consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with it. If you don't know how to accept then check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the data first:

```
 <script>
      $.ajax({
    url:"count.php",
    dataType:'json', 
    success: function(data, status){
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(data[0].online);
    }
  });
    </script>
```

Comment: It gives error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 87 of the JSON data